# sendJavascript doesn't works in InAppBrowser (migration from Cordova 2.7 to 3.6.4)

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

When I finished the migration, **CordovaActivity.sendJavascript** was marked as **deprecated**.

I call this method from an InAppBrowser Cordova Plugin and with 2.7 works but in Cordova 3.6.4 don't.

Console shows:

```
Set native->JS mode to null
```

How should i call sendJavascript in Cordova 3.6.4? What is the replacement for this deprecated method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use cordova plugins inside InAppBrowser, InAppBroser should be used just to display external websites without leaving your app

Anyway, you can execute javascript from the native part using this:

```
String js = "alert('test')";
yourInAppBrowserWebView.loadUrlNow("javascript:" + js);
```